# How to convert search value in nova?

Tags: anova, laravel-nova

I have one database table which contains all fields in that one of column is `amount`  which will store in the form of `cents` but in UI(Nova) i am showing as a `dollar`.

i am developing search it's working fine for `cents-search` now i want to search with dollar also, if user enters dollar value that should convert as cents how to achieve this thing in nova, please give me some idea how to do this one..

```
public static $search=['amount'];
```